# Easy RegExp doesnt match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match those URLs

```
de-de/checkout/
de-de/checkout/confirm/
```

with a RegExp. I've tried `/(.*)\/checkout\/(|$|confirm\/$)/g`, but I only get two matches

```
de-de/checkout/
de-de/checkout/
```

It's probably very easy but I don't have a clue why this isn't working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to match both with the same regex or one for each?

Comment: Hi Emil, both with the same.

Comment: `/(.*)\/checkout\/{0,1}(confirm{0,1}\/{0,1}){0,1}/ig`

Comment: Remove the first `|` - https://regex101.com/r/jguaaO/1

Comment: Paste your regexp into a regexp tester such as regex101 and read the English-like description.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen: Thanks, this works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: When I test your solution it with http://regexr.com/ I don't get a match. Thats weird.

Comment: You just did not set the multiline modifier (`m`). Do you have a multiline string input or separate strings in real life scenario?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Ok thanks, it was the multiline. In real life i don't have a multi line scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit easier to follow in my opinion:

```
(.+?)?\/checkout\/(?:confirm\/)?
```

Although I'm unsure whether you need to simply match the url (true/false) or capture `de-de` or whatever precedes or follows the samples you provide.

`confirm` is wrapped into a non-capturing group because it's the only path component which may or *may not* be there.

Comment: Perhaps, OP needs to make sure there is nothing after `checkout/` or `confirm/`, so I'd suggest keeping `$` - `/(.*?)\/checkout\/(?:confirm\/)?$/`

Answer (score 2):

```
(.*)\/checkout\/(confirm\/)?
```

two matches in regexr.com
that is considering either checkout or confirm is a keyword

Comment: more than that, please be more specific. What are urls you're targetting, etc etc

regards

Answer (score 1):

Remove the leading `|` in your alternation :

```
/(.*)\/checkout\/($|confirm\/$)/g
```

Regex will chose the shortest alternative of an unbounded alternation group, and you provided it with a 0-length match.
In its current state, your alternation meant "either nothing or the end of the string or confirm/ followed by the end of the string".

Comment: When it comes to alternations, it is not a good idea to use the *lazy* term (usually applied to quantifiers). *Regex is lazy* is a very ambiguous statement.

Comment: Well, you can also add that regex choses the shortest alternative in an unanchored alternation group since it makes no difference in anchored ones. The position at the end of the pattern is unanchored, and the first alternative that matches will "win" as per NFA regex specs.

Comment: @Toni2708 see [this one](http://regexr.com/3ek44). Note that I had to add the `m` multiline flag so that the `$` would match the end of the first line. If you're parsing line by line you shouldn't need this.

Comment: Also consider using @tmslnz 's answer which is cleaner in my opinion. I mainly wanted to provide you with an answer as for why your regex didn't work.